# ABP Adblock Plus which rule blockes JS

Tags: adblock

**Are there any hidden ABP AdBlockPlus hidden List which blocks ads?**

**Is it possible to see why a ressource is blocked by ad block plus (ADP)?**

I currently do have issues with adblock plus. I'd like to know why it blocks js libs.

I'm loading third party js libs from my own content distribution cdn (aws cloudfront). I cannot mention url here, since it is jquery, backbone and require and I don't like to become a public repository for them. I'm just ensuring the right version and availability through my own cdn though. ABP is blocking these scripts resulting in the typical `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` exception.

Anyhow it is pretty anoying to explain every customer why my app backend needs "ads" to function! :D

I checked against the easy listings:

- https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt
- https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylistgermany.txt

None of the easy listings matches any of my script urls!!! Yes I checked any tiny part of my url against hundrets of matches in the lists!

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Adblock Plus for Firefox allows you to see a list of all elements on a site that can be blocked, whether a filter was applied on an element, which filter it was and in which filter list the filter is included.

You can open this list by clicking on the Adblock Plus icon and selecting "Open blockable items".